# Is the canonical projection of $G$ onto $G/\ker f$ a lift of $f$?

Tags: group-theory, functions, intuition

I'm not sure I understand what a lift is and why it is called that. If I understand the definition correctly, then if I have a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$, then the canonical projection $\pi:G\to G/\ker f$ is a lift of $f$ with respect to the induced monomorphism $\phi:G/\ker f\to H.$ Is that correct? If so, sould you explain why this word is used? Somehow, my intuition is that it's $f$ that is "a lifted version" of $\phi,$ an $\pi$ is what "lifts" $\phi$ to $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have maps (of sets, groups, rings,...) $\,f:A\to B\,\;,\;\;g:C\to B\,$,  *a lift* is a map $\,h:A\to C\,$ s.t. $\,f=gh$ .

With your symbols, the canonical projection is a lift iff $\,f=\phi \pi\,$ ...which is true.